# How to search a string within another string which has spaces before or after for exact matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, string-search

I need to search a string within another string with exact match and without spaces in Python. For example searching string2 in string1 as below should be True (or a match, then I can convert it to True)

```
string1="car blue car"  
or string1="blue car"  
or string1="car blue"  

string2="blue"
```

searching below should be False

```
string1="car bluea window "  
string2="blue"
```

My string2 can be anywhere within the string1. I just need the exact matches. This also goes for digits. For example, below should be True

```
string1="blue 300 cars"  
string2="300"
```

but this should be False

```
string1="blue 30012 cars"  
string2="300
```

Built-in methods like contains or in do not work because they find the strings eventhough they are not exact matches. Regex search might seem like the solution but I couldn't find a successful regex expression to define such a case in re.search()

Comment: Do your string1 contains blank spaces always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex `\b{}\b` to solve this issue, for example, your code can look like this:

```
import re

def exact_match(string1, string2):
    pattern = r'\b{}\b'.format(string2)  
    match = re.search(pattern, string1)
    return bool(match)
```

For [**example here**](https://www.online-python.com/zZxKcBtCi3)

---

- The `\b` matches a word boundary.
- The `{}` is a placeholder for a string that will be inserted into the pattern. This allows you to create a regex pattern dynamically based on the value of a variable.

---

Note: if you have special characters used by the regex, you have to escape them by `re.escape()`:

```
match = re.search(pattern, re.escape(string1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I revised it a bit to fit it in my loop but works like a charm. For reference, in case anyone is looking, in terms of performance, having a function and calling it explicitly is faster than doing it as a list comprehension than calling any() to have True or False. It turns out any() has to go through each iteration again after map generator, which slows it down. I was surprised to see that

Answer (score 1):

If your string1 contain ' ' as you have given in the example, then:

```
string1="car blue car"
string2="blue"

string2 in string1.split()    # split will do ['car', 'blue', 'car']
#True 

string1="car blue car"
string2="blue"

string2 in string1.split()
#False

string1="blue 300 cars"  
string2="300"

string2 in string1.split()
#True

string1="blue 30012 cars"  
string2="300

string2 in string1.split()
#False
```